# wp_enqueue_style media queries still in sources/coverage?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media-queries

i have been trying to implement all the best-practices across the board, and starting with media queries i have used the "media" parameter in "wp_enqueue_style".

```
function nm_child_theme_styles() {
            // Enqueue child theme styles
            wp_enqueue_style( 'nm-child-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lawrence-dev-environment/client/dist/global.bundle.css' );
            
            // Checks if front page
            if ( is_front_page() ) {
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'nm-child-theme-front-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lawrence-dev-environment/client/dist/home.bundle.css' );
                    wp_enqueue_style( 'nm-child-theme-front-page-media', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/lawrence-dev-environment/client/dist/responsive/main-only-screen-and-min-width-768-px.css', array(), "1.0", 'only screen and (min-width: 768px)' );
            }
            
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nm_child_theme_styles', 100 ); // Note: Use priority "1000" to include the stylesheet after the parent theme stylesheets
```

There is just one problem, even though i included the "only screen and (min-width: 768px)", the style is loaded only for width above 768px, however in Chrome Dev Tools i can see on device width less than 768, it just shows as "unused bytes", so its bad on performance.

[image]

It does use it though at 768+, but i want it to ONLY be enqued when above 768, so mobile devices don't load unused code.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the `$media` string arguments in the `wp_enqueue_style` function is the equivalent to specifying the `media` attribute in the `<link>` element tag.

```html
eg: <link rel='stylesheet' href='my/path/to/script.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

If we take a look at the html5 documentation we can read the following:

> The `media` attribute specifies what media/device the target resource is optimized for.
> This attribute is mostly used with CSS style sheets to specify different styles for different media types.
> The `media` attribute can accept several values.

- Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

The media attribute **DOESN'T** restrict the actual script load to a specific media type, but instead restrict the script application to a specific media type.

Thinking out loud here, something similar to that thinking could be achieved by using the `get_browser` function see @ https://www.php.net/get_browser via php, or perhaps using some kind of conditional load based on `screen.width` via `js`.

```
if ( screen.width >= 600 ) {
  // scripts
};
```

### EDIT: Regarding your last comment about the yoast article

Unlike Javascript, `PHP` code is executed on the server, and the result is returned to the browser as plain HTML. The behaviour you're describing just can't be achieved with plain old `PHP`. In the yoast article you linked, they're using an npm package to achieve this behaviour.

Now the problem with that approach is that you're replacing a `css` request with a `js` request. You're just trading problems, and I would bet that the `js` request is more render blocking than the `css` request...

If you want to bypass any render blocking `css` issues you can inline load them straight into the `html`, in the `<head>` attribute.

Regarding performances, since Google came out with amp pages, I've started implemented them for my Wordpress projects. You can learn more about here @ https://amp.dev/ or just youtube it quickly to get an understanding. This is by far the best way to make a website page load instantaneously.

Comment: Alright thank you for the clarification, however i found this from https://developer.yoast.com/blog/a-better-faster-approach-to-css-in-wordpress-themes/, under "Media queries" section.

Looks like he gives another explanation than the one u did?

Comment: @zalador I've edited my answer in regards to the article you linked.